# Postfix: SMTP Relay based on alias (from address)

Tags: email, postfix

I recently noticed when I add an alias to a Gmail account they ask me for a remote SMTP server, username and password. Then, whenever I try to send an email using that alias it gets relayed by Gmail to the provided SMTP server.

Is there a way I can accomplish this setup on a Postfix install?

To clarify, on my server there's a virtual user `person@exemple.com` (with the aliases: `external.person@xpto.com` and `external.other@corpx.com`)  if he sends an email:

- With a `from` address of `person@exemple.com` => server will do the default delivery;
- With a `from` address of `external.person@xpto.com` => server will relay email using `smtp.xpto.com` (with proper credentials);
- With a `from` address of `external.other@corpx.com` => server will relay email using `smtp.corpx.com` (with proper credentials);

Ideally it would be nice If I could have a MySQL table with the external alises (for every virtual user) containing the external SMTP server domain, port, username and password. => This way I could setup a small web interface so my users could all their own external alises...

Thank you.

Comment: If I read your project correctly, your target is to store your users passwords so as to access their external accounts.

Comment: This is already done. Check the answer bellow.

Comment: Right. Then this is a storage of passwords in clear within `/etc/postfix/sender_credentials.cf`. As such, this is a major risk.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to encrypt the passwords and keep the functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can achieve this by tuning the `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` or `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` Postfix parameters. For example:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_maps.cf
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_credentials.cf
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may

# /etc/postfix/sender_maps.cf
external.person@xpto.com smtp:[smtp.xpto.com]:587
external.other@corpx.com smtp:[smtp.corpx.com]

# /etc/postfix/sender_credentials.cf
external.person@xpto.com xptouser:xptopassword
external.other@corpx.com corpxuser:corpxpassword
```

This example uses static hash tables. If your Postfix installation supports [mysql_table(5)](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html), you can use MySQL queries instead.

I am unable to test this solution now. I hope it works.

Comment: I tried `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` and it seems to work (after adding `smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous` to the config). However there's a strange behavior happening: After the external alias is added to `sender_*` if I try to send an email from the external server/address to postfix it gets bounced with:  `SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<person@exemple.com>:
   553 5.7.1 <external.person@xpto.com>: Sender address rejected:
   not logged in` any ideias? Ty.

Comment: Your Postfix installation tried to send messages to `smtp.xpto.com` without authentication credentials. I wonder if the credential lookup succeeds in your configuration. Please, try `postmap -q 'external.person@xpto.com' 'hash:/etc/postfix/sender_credentials.cf'` and check if credentials are returned correctly. For troubleshooting purposes, please set `soft_bounce = yes` and `debug_peer_list = .xpto.com` in your `main.cf` also.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will add `smtp_sasl_tls_security_options` to my answer instead. `smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous` is the default setting and removing `noplaintext` option is OK for encrypted SMTP sessions only.

Comment: So I had some settings to avoid users using each other local email alises, namely: `smtpd_sender_login_maps` / `smtpd_sender_restrictions = ... reject_sender_login_mismatch`. After disabling those everything works as expected, if I enable them I got the error above, how can I fix this? Why is postfix checking `sender_login_mismatch` on incoming email?

Comment: "Your Postfix installation tried to send messages to smtp.xpto.com without authentication credentials" => Check my last message. Your config works fine for sending email to `smtp.xpto.com`. However for receiving email from  `smtp.xpto.com` seems to fail because of the reason above...

Comment: If you use `reject_sender_login_mismatch` restriction, Postfix will check `smtpd_sender_login_maps` for all incoming mail. I suggest you to use `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` instead.

Comment: I had just discovered that option as well ahah, do you know if that might rise any security implications? Thank you.

Comment: I guess malicious users may be able to send forged messages to internal destinations only (because of `reject_unauth_destination, permit`, for example). It depends on how your `smtpd_*_restrictions` are configured. SPF or DKIM may mitigate this specific risk. I'm not able to figure anything now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've been running some tests, trying to change headers, users etc in/out the network and it seems to be as secure as before.

Comment: Btw, for reference, I changed to `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` because it looks more appropriate to leave the transport maps alone. That forced me to remove the `smtp:` part from `/etc/postfix/sender_maps.cf`. Now it looks like: `external.person@xpto.com smtp.xpto.com:587`.

Comment: I would not remove the braces in `$sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`. If you specify a `$relayhost` without them, Postfix will make MX lookups instead of connecting directly to the intended server.

Comment: `external.person@xpto.com [smtp.xpto.com]:587` works fine, however the original `external.person@xpto.com smtp:[smtp.xpto.com]:587` gives me: `fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: smtp:[smtp.xpto.com]:587`.