# Postfix: Sender Credentials Password Storage

Tags: postfix, authentication

A few weeks ago I was trying to implement a gmail-like SMTP relay / aliases system on Postfix here: [Postfix: SMTP Relay based on alias (from address)](https://serverfault.com/questions/767687/postfix-smtp-relay-based-on-alias-from-address)

After posting a solution for the question one user (@danielAzuelos) pointed out that storing postfix's sender credentials in plain text could be a security issue.

Is there a way to store them in a safe way and retain the functionality explained on the question/answer?

Comment: define 'safe way'. If the people who can access the file with the passwords are the admins of the host, and you trust those people, then it's safe. If you do not trust them, you have bigger problems than this file. Obviously, if anybody can read that file, that could be a problem. As far as I know, there is no other way to relay mail through gmail from postfix.

Comment: @natxoasenjo what if the server is compromised? I do trust the people with access to the passwords...

Comment: then you disconnect if from the network, change all passwords and restore from backups